# Error Code 1560 vs 1570 when Saving to Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

What is the difference between both error code when saving core data? Reading from some posts, both of them refer to same error description: The mandatory field is not filled. Is there any more specific different? Because sometimes I get 1560 error code, but I also can get 1570 error code. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `1560` is a multiple-errors error. From the [Core Data Constants Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Miscellaneous/CoreData_Constants/Reference/reference.html).

```
NSValidationMultipleErrorsError                  = 1560,
NSValidationMissingMandatoryPropertyError        = 1570,
```

Sounds like you're getting multiple `1570`s which are being delivered in an `NSError` with the `1560` code.

Answer (score 1):

To agree with Mark Adams, I had 1560 code as a parent error to many 1570s.  For me, this occurred when I had a child class marked as 'not optional' while the parent was 'optional', so I should have cascaded a delete.  Once I set the parent delete rule to Cascade this worked for me.  Obviously it will depend on the functionality you want.

[Relationship: I had to set the Delete rule to Cascade in my case.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjCUP.png)

Comment: I had the 1570 for two inverse relations that were with "Cascading delete". I fixed changing to "Nullify".